# swagger node ValidationError: "body" is required

Tags: node.js, swagger

I asked another question in another thread that gave me start on Swagger POST, but here I am stuck with another problem.

Here is my parameter definitions in my config json file

```
"/people/postTest": {
  "post": {
    "summary": "post test.",
    "description": "Test.",
    "operationId": "postTest",
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
      ],
    "tags": [
      "test post"
    ],
    "parameters": [
    {
        "in":"body",
        "name":"body",
        "description": "body for the POST request",
        "required":true,
        "schema": {"$ref":"#/definitions/inBody"}
      }

    ] }} 

"definitions": {
     "inBody": {

  "properties": {
    "RequestSystem": {
      "type": "string"
    }}}}
```

(copied it from a big file so only took a small part but there is no issues with syntax)

and I am using CURL to post my request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"RequestSystem":"IVR"}' http://localhost:8016/people/postTest
```

and this is the validation error I am getting when I try to start my node server

```
**ValidationError: "body" is required**
```

I know I am passing "RequestSystem" parameter but I am not sure where I am making mistakes in setting up my params in my config json file's "parameters". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make `required=false`

```
[
{
    "in":"body",
    "name":"body",
    "description": "body for the POST request",
    "required":false,
    "schema": {"$ref":"#/definitions/inBody"}
  }
] 
}
}
```

Try this It should work.

Comment: MANISH, thanks for the response. I made it "required":false as you suggested. Now the validation is passed through. But when I have a console.log (req.body) in my REST service is giving me "undefined". What am I missing? any suggestions?

Comment: In your REST services body perimeter name is same as `RequestSystem`. If not use same name as a body property

Comment: Thanks again. Here is my REST service on node, and express js. app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.post("/people/testPost", function (req, res) {
console.log("I am in the testPost service);  //this gets printed
console.log("The req body", req.body)   //says 'undefined'                            so now to access RequestSystem here, what should I be doing? I thought that param comes in something like this "req.body.RequestSystem"..

Comment: try to print `req` I think it should get printed. If not try to convert the `req` into string and print. Actually `req` don't have `body` property so you are getting that error .

Comment: I printed req and I did not find 'body' or 'RequestSystem'. Do you want to see any specific part of that long 'req' object? let me know I can post it here...but here is what I see towards end of that req  Route {
     path: '/people/postTest',
     stack: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } },
  body: undefined }